# JQuery Integration with JavaEE

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have been able to use Jquery with ASP.NET because I know where to drop the JQuery Library, but I am trying to integrate JQuery with Java Web Applications using JSP's,Servlets, etc.

It seems like a trivial question, but for some reason I am unable to figure out where to drop the JQuery Javascript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it under your web structure. (i.e.)

`webroot/static/scripts/jquery/jquery.js`

So you can acces from:
http://host:port/webroot/static/scripts/jquery/jsquery.js

The web structure is kindly arbitrary (expect for the `WEB-INF` directory).
All the resource are public under the root, expect (again) the resources under `WEB-INF`.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to modify headers of html files you can load the jQuery library with [Google CDN for Ajax Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/) without having to drop it physically on your server anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RichFaces, jQuery support is pretty-much built-in.  You can use jQuery on your page after doing this, in the head section:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
```

Then you can use jQuery by calling "jQuery('selector goes here')".  Richfaces uses '$' for it's own purposes, so calling "$('selector goes here')" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Digital web platforms, put jquery.js in a folder /javascripts following the Twitter Bootstrap convention.

If you are using JSF 2.x then under folder /resources/javascripts